# HQL query with two joins expressed in Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the Hibernate HQL query, which seems to do its job perfectly, but I am currently experimenting a bit with Hibernate Criteria API and would like to express the same HQL query with Criteria API. In this particular example I have two joins in HQL query, where my second join uses alias from my first join. I would like to achieve something identical with Criteria API. Is this possible?

Here is the original query:

```
select mt 
from MessageThread mt 
  inner join mt.messageThreadsStatuses ts 
  inner join ts.threadLocations tl 
where ts.user.userId = :userId and tl = 0";
```

Here is the rewritten query, which does not work for me:

```
Criteria c = sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MessageThread.class) 
    .createAlias("messageThreadsStatuses", "ts").setFetchMode("ts", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .createAlias("ts.threadLocations", "tl").setFetchMode("tl", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("ts.user.userId", userId))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("tl", 0));
```

I tried for example also to define the second alias as:

```
.createAlias("threadLocations", "tl").setFetchMode("tl", FetchMode.JOIN)
```

but without success.

Comment: What is it doing? is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the following document http://billingb.livejournal.com/34266.html:

Solving both these problems is easy if you use aliases and each criteria object you create. I think the big mistake is that most examples show all the criteria creations chained together, but you can pull them apart and everything becomes easier to understand. The solution code I came up with looks like:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Parameter.class);
Criteria cx = c.createCriteria("masterCollections");
cx.createAlias("datasetEntry", "de");
cx.createAlias("parameters", "par");
c.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.in("de.datasetId",datasetIDList), Restrictions.in("par.parameterId", parameterIDList)));
```